# How to configure an app on Google App Engine to Receive Email on any email address?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

As we know if we want to enable our app on App Engine to receive emails, we need to first configure an email address of the format `string@appid.appspotmail.com` in web.xml file. However, I wanted to know if it is possible to use an email address of the form `string@domain.com` which can be used to receive emails for the application. Like you can map you `appid@appspot.com` to your own domain, and it works fine but wanted to know if it is possible do it for emails also somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just direct your mail server for domain.com to forward string@domain.com to string@your-appid.appspotmail.com or your-appid@appspot.com. The inbound email processor doesn't care what the original "to" address is -- it will process it regardless. You have access to the headers programmatically, so you can decide to treat it differently depending on what email it came in through, if you want.

Comment: To be clear -- the MX records for your domain.com has to point to a mail server that is handling the mail for that domain. Whatever mail server is referenced in those MX records for domain.com (or the email client that receives the mail from that server for the addressing you're wanting to use) has to handle the routing/forwarding for anything@domain.com to the app engine inbound email account.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, will check it with my domain Admin. Can you please elaborate more on programmatic access to headers, can you please give some links to code examples and how can we get the original sender of the email it has been forwarded by the email server based on MX records.

Comment: If you setup the route/forward directly in your mail server, the to/cc/date/etc. fields should be left untouched. The message object that is available through App Engine will have the original values when you call getFrom(), for example. Check out https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving?hl=ja . And, the MX records don't have anything to do with forwarding -- they just map the domain to which mail server(s) handle that domain. Bottom line: if you can setup a forward/route in your mail server for one address to an appspotmail address, it should be straightforward from there.